# Google Geo Chart does not render inside Angular Material mdTabs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-visualization, angular-material

I am using [Google Geo chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart) inside [Angular Material tabs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdTabs).

The chart renders fine for the first time when you load the page, but when you change pages and come back to this page it gives a container error and the charts don't load.

Unfortunately can't replicate this error on and editor to explain the bug.

Is anyone aware any fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the directive and also Make sure you have the chart loaded initially,

```
  var app = angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial', 'googlechart']);
    app.controller('ChartController', function($scope) {
      var chart1 = {};
      chart1.type = "GeoChart";
      chart1.data = [
        ['Locale', 'Count', 'Percent'],
        ['Germany', 22, 23],
        ['United States', 34, 11],
        ['Brazil', 42, 11],
        ['Canada', 57, 32],
        ['France', 6, 9],
        ['RU', 72, 3]
      ];
      chart1.options = {
        width: 600,
        height: 300,
        chartArea: {
          left: 10,
          top: 10,
          bottom: 0,
          height: "100%"
        },
        colorAxis: {
          colors: ['#aec7e8', '#1f77b4']
        },
        displayMode: 'regions'
      };
      chart1.formatters = {
        number: [{
          columnNum: 1,
          pattern: "$ #,##0.00"
        }]
      };
      $scope.chart = chart1;
    })
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/f4TDbe?p=preview)**